# 100% viewport height working on large monitor but not laptop?

Tags: css, html

I'd like to make my hero image to fit 100% height of the viewport. I achieved this by adding `height: 100vh;` to the class="video-hero" (stretches the image gradient) and added to increase the image size added a class to the image `video-hero-placeholder-small.jpg` with  `height: 100vh;`.

However this is resulting in an odd grey section to the right of the image (when on my laptop) but appears to not be an issue on my large side monitor.

I have a min-width of 100% if when removed centers the image on my laptop but not on my large side monitor. Could this be related to the issue?

```
.video-hero__media-wrapper
{
min-width : 100%
}
```

Video demonstration: https://www.screencast.com/t/Oftl68noHO

Video demonstration explained: On the right side of the video (my laptop screen) the hero image doesn't stretch full width (instead shows the odd grey section), I then bring it onto my large side monitor and it mysteriously works?

**HTML**

```
    <div class="hero">
    <div class="video-hero video-hero--featured"></div>
    ::before
    <div class="video-hero__media-wrapper">
    <picture>
           <img class="big-home-image" src="https://wb.workbooks.com/resources/=QzM/using-crm-on-a-laptop.jpg" alt="Using Workbooks CRM on a laptop">
    </picture>
        </div>
    <div class="video-hero__content"></div>
    </div>
<div class="video-hero__content">
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.video-hero {
    height: 100vh;
    padding-top: 420px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**Screen resolution of large monitor:**
1920x1200

**Screen resolution of laptop:**
1366x768

**URL of website:**
https://workbooks.com - Live site so I've not applied the changes to the viewport height.

Comment: It has something to do with the aspect ratio of the video. The min-height 100% wont make the video stretch in the width otherwise it will get stretched out. 
Dont know or this explanation is clear. Nice screen capture BTW.

Comment: Thanks, I use Jing and it's free! Not sure what the takeaway is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few typos in this code, but when I set the hero img width to 100% and the video-hero wrapper class to 100vh, it looked right on a laptop and desktop monitor.

Comment: Thanks exactly what do you mean by you set the hero img width to 100%? As I can't seem to replicate this myself.

Comment: I mean to set the width of the img in your picture element to 100%. Removing the padding-top and setting the height to 100vh on the .video-hero class makes things appear as you'd expect. The issue you were seeing probably has to do with the placeholder srcsets in your theme. I'm guessing if you hit refresh and make these changes your issue will resolve. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! This solved the issue as I'd set the height on both to 100vh and not added in the width!